# Microsoft Teams - Updating the Tab Url

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to update URL of Microsoft team tab at runtime, I have checked in the MSDN blog and it seems that it updates only the description of the tab not the URL using graph API call (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{groupid}/channels/{channelid}/tabs/{tabid}). Could anyone suggest how to update tab URL as well?

I have tried calling the below graph API, but it updates only the tab name
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{groupid}/channels/{channelid}/tabs/{tabid}

```
{  
  "displayName": "My Contoso Tab - updated",
}
```

Microsoft teams tab URL should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

> The web URL(deep link) part you are trying to update, It is an system generated
>   value which can't be changed.